# Android Studio NullPointerException, trying to use parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use Parse.com for the user login/signup activity for my apps, and I am learning how to use it by following this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/ . But after I typed in everything, my app keep crashing and giving NullPointerException

And here is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.ed.parselogintutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "T9so2huSfs1xMHwEjx9vSeUuKeyBZsXVyG4QHi7K", "yiQz0RMs9TCkWu8EsdsoVxcPWGlTyAmO20JuEh0X");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Determine whether the current user is an anonymous user
        if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
            //If user is anonymous, send the user to LoginSignupActivity.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LoginSignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            //If current user is no anonymous user
            //Get current user data from Parse.com
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null) {
                //Send logged in users to Welcome.class
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                //Send User to LoginSignupActivity.class
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        LoginSignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the stack

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ed.parselogintutorial/com.example.ed.parselogintutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.parse.ParseUser.isLinked(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

asdsa

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.parse.ParseUser.isLinked(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseAnonymousUtils.java:51)
        at com.example.ed.parselogintutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)  
        android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I am sorry if there is a very clear mistake here as I am new to android development, please anyone who used Parse.com before or have any knowledge regarding this error, please teach me how to solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem or not as I'm not familiar with Parse, but you're calling the Parse methods from an Activity class whereas the tutorial is calling them from an Application class.

Comment: Oh yeah I missed the ParseApplication class, thank you for noticing it. I will try to create the ParseApplication now. Thank you

Comment: After I added the ParseApplication class, it turns out this error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ed.parselogintutorial/com.example.ed.parselogintutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library. 

How do I call the ParseApplication class in the MainActivity ? Sorry for stupid questions, Need help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the comments below in the tutorial, there are issues with the given code. Here is the suggestions from one of the comments:

> It's early so I am not that sure what they were going for here... Get
>   rid of the ParseApplication.java and put this in your
>   mainactivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); <<----UNDER THIS (left in for location purpose)

// Add your initialization code here

Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

// If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this

// line.

defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

// Determine whether the current user is an anonymous user

if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) { <<----(left in for location purpose)
```

Essentially, the problem is that you're not calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); before you try to call Parse functions.

Comment: Actually I solved it, the problem is that I didn't write this line :android:name="ParseApplication" in the AndroidManifest in the application. Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.